# How do I create a nested json format in django rest serializer?

Tags: json, django, api, rest, serialization

Currently I have this format in the API response

```
"inner_divertor": {
  "volume": 5.2,
  "volume_units": "m^2",
  "volume_notes": "xyz"
},
 "outer_divertor": {
  "volume": null,
  "volume_units": "m^3",
  "volume_notes": null
}
```

I'm trying to add a "volume" field and nest the fields inside it. The goal is to have someting like:

```
"inner_divertor": {
  volume:{
    "volume": 4.3,
    "volume_units": "m^2",
    "volume_notes": "xyz" 
  }
},
"outer_divertor": {
  volume: {
    "volume": null,
    "volume_units": "m^3",
    "volume_notes": null
  }
}
```

Here are the the serializers:

```
class InnerDivertorSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InnerDivertor
        fields = ('volume', 'volume_units', 'volume_notes')

class OuterDivertorSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OuterDivertor
        fields = ('volume', 'volume_units', 'volume_notes')
```

Comment: Can you show your models

Answer (score 0):

Well accorrding to this link Document, https://pypi.org/project/drf-flex-fields/

I dont think you should seperate `inner_divertor`, `outer_divertor` into two seperate classes since they are on the same level of hierarchy.

Instead of that try this:

```
class DivertorSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Divertor
        fields = ('inner_divertor', 'outer_divertor')
        expandable_fields = {
            'inner_divertor': VolumnSerializer,
            'outer_divertor': VolumnSerializer
        }

class VolumnSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Volumn
        fields = ('volume', 'volume_units', 'volume_notes')
```

More importantly you need to have Volumn and Divertor `model`